# How can I add CommandBar buttons in SharePoint online using JSOM?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, jsom, modern-team-site

[image]

As shown in figure I want to add button (right side by send by mail) on each CommandBar in SharePoint site?

Comment: Are you trying to add this command on all modern SharePoint pages or somewhere else??

Comment: All modern sharepoint pages..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert some code into [React script editor web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to append the custom button.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var commandset= $("button[name='Send by email'][role='menuitem']").parent().parent();
        commandset.append( "<p>Test</p>" );
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [SharePoint Framework Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions) to do this.